# Going from non-linear root-finding to multi-objective optimization

Tags: python, optimization, ipopt, deap, objective-function

To simplify, let's say I can describe a system with

variables `x1` and `x2`,

parameters `p1` and `p2`, and

constraints `f(x, p) = 0` and `g(x, p) = 0`:

For example:

`f(x1, x2, p1, p2) = x1^2 * p1 + x1^2 * p2 + x2 = 0`

`g(x1, x2, p1, p2) = x2^2 * p2 + x1 * p1 = 0`

Now, let's say that given the true value of parameters `p1` and `p2`, the root(s) exist(s).
However, in my case, the parameters are determined in an imperfect way and a non-linear root-finder like `scipy.optimize`'s `fsolve` is unsuccessful. One could feed in the parameters as variables and try to find the roots, but increase the variables and the parameters by an order of magnitude, like in my actual system, and the constraints become very difficult to respect.

Therefore, I've been looking at optimization packages in python that could "solve" my set of non-linear equations. And this is where my lack of understanding of optimization presents a roadblock.

If I understand correctly, as posited, my equations are constraints, meaning that they must be respected for my design to be successful. However, I've realized that given the imperfect nature of the parameters (or the large number of possible variables), I need to have one (or several) objective functions to minimize as opposed to constraints.

All the equations that describe my system have equal validity, so I don't think I can simply choose one or several equations to be objective functions and the rest remain as constraints. It looks like I need to have all my equations as objective functions.

I therefore have two questions:

1. Is my logic to have all my equations as objective functions valid, and
2. What python package would allow me to minimize these objective functions?

I have looked at `cyipopt`, `casadi`, `pyomo`, and `DEAP`, but I am a bit lost. I think once my model of my system is better defined, I will know exactly what to look for. However, if code for my simple example can be provided, I would really appreciate it.

P.S: My model as it stands now has 11 variables and 11*5 parameters (five coefficients representing a 4th degree polynomial for each variable). I can also add constraints to the variables if necessary in the optimization package.

Comment: I would formulate a least-squares problem: minimize the sum of squares of the deviations (a.k.a. slacks) of the equations. If the optimal objective is close to zero, you should declare victory. Also, non-convexity can be an issue. Try some different starting points to make sure you are not in some local optimum.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion Erwin. Do you have any recommendations for a python package that can do this? Or is any optimizer that can minimize an objective function suitable?

Comment: This is a very small problem, so any unconstrained NLP solver will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With equations:

```py
e1 = x1**2 * p1 + x1**2 * p2 + x2
e2 = x2**2 * p2 + x1 * p1
```

it is possible to solve the system of equations as hard constraints (equality form):

```py
m.Equation(e1==0)
m.Equation(e2==0)
```

or as soft constraints (minimize objective):

```py
m.Minimize(e1**2)
m.Minimize(e2**2)
```

This approach works in Pyomo, CasADi, and Gekko. Here is a [Gekko](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) example that uses both approaches:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO    
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO()
x = m.Array(m.Var,2,value=2)
x1,x2 = x
p = m.Array(m.Param,2,value=1)
p1,p2 = p
e1 = x1**2 * p1 + x1**2 * p2 + x2
e2 = x2**2 * p2 + x1 * p1

# approach #1
m.Equation(e1==0)
m.Equation(e2==0)

# approach #2
m.Minimize(e1**2)
m.Minimize(e2**2)

m.options.SOLVER=1
m.solve()
print('x: ', x)
print('Objective: ',m.options.OBJFCNVAL)
```

In this case, the solutions are the same by using one or the other (or both). If it is a large-scale optimization problem, the solver may not reduce `e1` or `e2` to zero with soft constraints. Sometimes including both can help the solver find a solution.

Comment: I have one final question: is it doable to have many, many soft/hard constraints? I would like to use this approach to optimize several datasets that share variables, which, traditionally, could be solved individually with multiple linear regression. Now instead, I combine all the datasets together and have one global optimization problem where each soft/hard constraint is a different row in the global Y=Xβ+ϵ dataset.

Comment: Please see my StackExchange question as motivation for this global optimization approach: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4265365/estimating-coefficients-through-multiple-linear-regression-from-several-data-set

Comment: That is certainly possible. For very large datasets, you may need to use a specialized QP solver because of the `m.Minimize(e**2)` terms. If you can make it linear then there are even more efficient Linear Programming or explicit solutions to linear regression that just rely on matrix manipulations.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The only terms that are non-linear in my problem at the moment are interactive terms. For example `x1*x3*p1 + x2*x3*p2 + x1*p3 + x2*p4 = y`. Do you know if and how it is possible to linearize the interactive, multiplicative terms? If I am able to have a completely linear problem, could you explain (or point me to resources that explain) how I could use linear programming or solve explicitly with matrix manipulations? Thank you.

Comment: I'd recommend that you stay with a nonlinear or quadratic programming solver for that problem. Gekko can solve nonlinear programming problems. There is information here on linearization if that is your only option: https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/ModelLinearization

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I only have on the order of 10 equations, which can be inputted manually, but those equations are equal (hard) or approaching (soft) on the order of 10,000 values. My approach would be to flip the problem on its head and have the corresponding `values` vector as a parameter in each equation: `y = m.Param(value=values)` and then subtract it from the corresponding equation `e1 = x1*x3*p1 + x2*x3*p2 + x1*p3 + x2*p4 - y`. Finally, if I am not mistaken, for each equation, I would only have one constraint (*e.g.*, `m.Equation(e1==0)`) instead of ~10,000! Would this work?

Comment: One equation applied to multiple data rows is best done with `IMODE=2`. Here is an example: https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/ParameterFit

Comment: I've implemented your example for **multiple** equations applied to multiple data rows; however, I'm getting the error `'Data arrays must have the same length, and match time discretization in dynamic problems'`. You probably know the easy fix; however, in the case that it is a limitation of gekko, here is some info: on line 159 of the file gk_write_files.py, `length =np.size(np.array(vp.value).flatten())` does not update with the first GKParameter of the second equation, since `first_array == True`, thereby raising the Exception.

Comment: Check the list that is fed into .value as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71302626/gekko-arx-model-forecasting-data-arrays-must-have-the-same-length  If this doesn't help then please create a new question with minimal code that reproduces the error.

Comment: I just created a new questions explaining my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73112525/multiple-equations-minimized-in-regression-imode-of-gekko. Thanks again for all the help!